# How to upgrade/refresh the ag-grid after row delete?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have an ag grid where i am trying to delete a row...I am able to remove the row from data source using "splice" technique,after that i want to refresh the table.But it is showing error.This is the code which i am using to delete a row

```
selectedvalue={} //this holds the selected row value
rowData=[]; //this holds all the row data
onRowSelected(event) {
  this.selectedvalue = event;
 }
deletebtn() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.rowData.length; i++) {
        if (this.selectedvalue.node.data.make === this.rowData[i].make) {
            this.rowData.splice(i, 1);
            this.gridOptions.api.refreshView();
        }
    }
}
```

It is showing erroe something like this-->  Cannot read property 'refreshView' of undefined...How can watch the changes made in table after row delete.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Edit: This solution is for version **3.3.x** (updated plnkr link)

You should set the rows into the grid again:
after your splice:

```
gridOptions.api.setRowData(gridOptions.rowData)
```

Maybe this plunkr helps https://plnkr.co/plunk/0k4sYa

<s>The author of ag-grid explains this in the ag-grid forum</s> The forum no longer exist

Comment: Ugh can you provide a link to the ag-grid forum where this is explained? I've registered but I'm not an Enterprise user, so maybe that's why I cannot search properly for that explanation.

Comment: I'm not an enterprise user as well. But, you can still search the forum without one.
Like this one https://ag-grid.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=3726&pid=8876&highlight=setRowData#pid8876

Comment: Thanks! I was unable to find that in the forums, but it turns out that the answer is not entirely up-to-date. See the answer from @user3294566 below. However, your answer is correct for the early 2016 versions of agGrid; newer versions just have much better API calls to easily accomplish the removal of a row and subsequent refresh.

Comment: The Plunker is 404 :-(    Is `gridOptions.api.setRowData(gridOptions.rowData)` enough, or is it necessary to `gridOptions.api.refreshClientSideRowModel()` afterwards?

Comment: Hi @MawgsaysreinstateMonica . I've updated the plnkr link, plnkr changed the link method. See the script for the setRowData, as for that ag-grid version, it is the only thing required. Be ware of the ag-grid version as Gwyneth mentions.

Comment: There is no forum anymore. please add updated link. thanks

Answer (score 13):

There is a more efficient way described in the documentation : [Transaction Update API](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/data-update-transactions/#transaction-update-api).

You must use the method `api.applyTransaction` after the rows are deleted :

```
gridOptions.api.applyTransaction({ remove: [array of rows you have deleted]});
```

For example with just one row deleted :

```
gridOptions.api.applyTransaction({ remove: [this.rowData[i]]})
```

With this method, the grid will just update the rows in parameters and keeps all other view states (order, ...).

To complete the answer, there are also parameters to update the grid when adding or modifying one or more lines.

**When adding :**

```
gridOptions.api.applyTransaction({ add: [array of rows you have added]});
```

**When modifying :**

```
gridOptions.api.applyTransaction({ update: [array of rows you have changed]});
```

*Remarks : for older versions of AG Grid the method was api.updateRowData instead of api.applyTransaction*

Comment: Property gridOptions does not exist

Comment: `updateRowData()` is replaced by `applyTransaction()`

Answer (score 7):

For better performance, use grid api calls to add/remove rows.
To insert a row at the beginning, that is copy of a selected row:

```
var rowData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(selectedNode.data));
gridOptions.api.insertItemsAtIndex(0, [rowData]);
```

To remove a selected row:

```
var selectedNodes = gridOptions.api.getSelectedNodes();
gridOptions.api.removeItems(selectedNodes);
```

Please insert new row only after a deep copy of original row.
Otherwise, api continues to refer to the same row.
So, the subsequent remove of new row, will remove original row from grid.

Please refer documentation for api details.
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-insert-remove/

Comment: You're not using `newRow` anywhere on the insert... instead, you have `rowData`. I guess you need to change that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! While it's now obvious to me, there have been changes to the way agGrid works in mid-2017 — the original question was asked in 2016 — and I actually had an *outdated* version of agGrid, where your own answer (which is correct for the current version of agGrid!) did not work, i.e. the JS console got some errors for missing API functions. Indeed, you answer (which I have upvoted :-) ) is the more correct, up-to-date method to accomplish what the OP asked — there is *no* need to feed *all* the rows again to agGrid, as it seemed to be the case in early 2016.

Answer (score 3):

`$events.refreshInfiniteCache();`

you can use this simply for update your grid

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer for newer versions of agGrid.

### From version `23.1.0+`: Use [`applyTransaction(transaction)`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update-transactions/)

```js
gridApi.applyTransaction({ remove: rowArray });

// similarly you can add or update using transaction
gridApi.applyTransaction({ update: rowArray});
gridApi.applyTransaction({ add: rowArray});
```

Where `rowArray` is an array of row data. Existing rows data can be accessed from `RowNode.data`.

#### Example

```js
onRemoveFirst() {
  const firstRow = this.gridApi.getRenderedNodes()[0].data;

  if (!firstRow) return;
  this.gridApi.applyTransaction({ remove: [firstRow] });
}

onRemoveSelected() {
  const selectedData = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
  this.gridApi.applyTransaction({ remove: selectedData });
}

onThanos() {
  const itemsToRemove = [];

  this.gridApi.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort((rowNode) => {
    const shouldThanos = randomBetween(1, 100) <= 50;

    if (shouldThanos) {
      itemsToRemove.push(rowNode.data);
    }
  });
  this.gridApi.applyTransaction({ remove: itemsToRemove });
}
```

#### Live Demo

[image: Edit 35311052/how-to-upgrade-refresh-the-ag-grid-after-row-delete/]

Comment: applyTransaction is not updating the underlying data array. How to get the full data set (including the modification) Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 1):

To update the data in a particular cell of aggrid

```
        let rowNode = f.gridApi.getRowNode(f.id);  // use to find the rowNode
        rowNode.setDataValue('myPrice','1000') // update the datavalue in the price cell
```

f is current node of the aggrid

Answer (score 0):

Below is how i delete Rows from my AgGrid.

1. Select 1 or more rows using ridApi.getSelectedNodes.
2. Map through the selected rows and take out the index of the given row.
3. Use array method filter to filter out all the rows that are not selected
4. Spread the filtered rows with the old rows

   ```
   const selectedRows: RowNode[] = this.gridApi.getSelectedNodes();
   const rowsToRemove = selectedRows.map(node => node.rowIndex);
   const filteredRows = allRows.filter((_, i) => !rowsToRemove.includes(i));

   this.rowData = [...filteredRows]
   ```

hope this help to anyone in need of it!